# Pessimistic lock implemented with spring data redis, setNX method returns null

Tags: spring, redis

This error shows up after I upgraded spring-data-redis from 1.4.2 to 1.5.2.

My code is to implement a pessimistic lock,

```
redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean doInRedis(RedisConnection connection)
                        throws DataAccessException {
Boolean nx = connection.setNX(lockKey.getBytes(), identifier.getBytes());
return nx;
}};
```

Checked all fields not null. The setNx method always returns null. It should return boolean true or false.

Any help is appreciated.

**Updates**:

Above code snippet was nested in another `SessionCallback` Redis transaction. It used to work under spring-data-redis 1.4.2. To fix "ERR EXEC without MULTI" reported at [ERR EXEC without MULTI - spring redis+jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699007/err-exec-without-multi-spring-redisjedis), I upgraded the lib to 1.5.2, and the problem suddenly showed up.

To fix it, I first tried to assign a different redisTemplate (prototype bean) for the nested callback method, but it didn't work. The **working solution** is to break up and flatten the single transaction into 4, "test if lock is needed", "acquire lock", "do the business", "release lock".

Comment: The issue was fixed.

Comment: please add an answer, optimally with the code you used to fix it

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was caused by nesting Redis transactions. Nesting `SessionCallback` even with distinct redisTemplate (different database connections) fails the nested transaction. The working solution is to flatten to 4 transactions, "test if lock is needed", "acquire lock", "do the business", "release lock".